# Access other users with admin via SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal, remote, administrator, user

I have the admin password to a remote computer(mac). How can I access another user that I do not have the password of?

Comment: What makes you think you should have access to a resource you don't have the required credentials for? It sounds counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the sudo password, then you should be able to run:

```
sudo su <username>
```

This will set your uid to the user you decide to login as.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already root then sudo is not necessary. Just do

```
su - <username>
```

Without "-" it will not ne a login shell ie the UID/GID will be changed but the environment will not be updated.